# change spatial resolution

Tags: raster, erdas-imagine, modis, resolution

I have two types of image, one of them is a TRMM image with 0.25 degree cells and the other one is a MODIS image with 1 km spatial resolution. 
How can I change my TRMM image resolution to 1 km without GCP points?

Comment: What software do you have available?

Comment: my software is Erdas imagine 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

you can use gdal to do this if your input data is georeferenced, with [gdalwarp](http://gdal.gloobe.org/gdal/gdalwarp.html)

you will need to specify the output size (-tr 1000 1000), the resampling method (-r bilinear) and I guess the projection of MODIS as output ( -t_srs "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs" )

so it should look like this in command line

gdawarp -tr 1000 1000 -r bilinear -t_srs "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs" input_TRMM.tif output_TRMM.tif